# How to display this array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

The following array is specified. These values are booleans in a mysql database. They represent facilities of one row:

```
<?php 

$facilitiesgroup1=array();
$facilitiesgroup2=array();

$facilitiesgroup1[1]="Red";
$facilitiesgroup1[2]="Black";
$facilitiesgroup1[3]="Wite";
$facilitiesgroup1[4]="Green";

$facilitiesgroup2[1]="Swimming";
$facilitiesgroup2[2]="Bowling";
$facilitiesgroup2[3]="Tennis";
$facilitiesgroup2[4]="Football";

?>
```

How can I display these on the page of a specific record? (delimited by comma, except for the last one)

---------update--------------
@Chris
To be as precise as I can..
I mean that e.g. $facilitiesgroup1[1]="Red" element is represented in a mysql table by 'facilitiesgroup1_1' field, and when it is checked (true), than that property (record) has this facility (Red).

That's what I would like to display in the individual property page after executing a query in a grouped list, like:

```
<p><strong>Facilities-Group-1:</strong><br />
<?php
echo implode($facilitiesgroup1,', ');?>
</p>
<br />
<p><strong>Facilities-Group-2:</strong><br />
<?php
echo implode($facilitiesgroup2,', ');?>
</p>
```

Of course the above code alone doesn't do the job, beacuse it lists all facilities defined in the array, regardless of what is checked in that row of the database.

Answer (score 2):

First off, the values aren't [boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), they're [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Second, if you can prevent them from being in two different arrays, it will be cleaner and easier to work with:

```
$facilitiesgroups=array();
$facilitiesgroups[] = array (
    "Red",
    "Black",
    "Wite",
    "Green"
);
$facilitiesgroups[] = array (
    "Swimming",
    "Bowling",
    "Tennis",
    "Football"
);
```

Then, you can use something like this (to make each array comma-delimited with a new line in between,. like CSV):

```
function make_csv_row(&$item) {
    $item = implode(',', $item);
}
array_walk($facilitiesgroups, 'make_csv_row');
implode("\n", $facilitiesgroups);
```

Otherwise, as demonstrated above, just use `implode`:

```
echo implode(',', facilitiesgroup1);
echo implode(',', facilitiesgroup2);
```

**Documentation**

- [array](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php)
- [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)
- [implode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: OK, thanks, implode works well. But what if every element of an array is bound to a mysql field (true/false), and I would like to display array elements which are checked, according to a query?

(Sorry for having been not accurate, I'm not so good even in questioning php issues, since I'm just trying to convert an asp site to php)

@Aurelio

Comment: I am still not understanding how the database part factors in here.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo implode(",",$facilitiesgroup1)
echo implode(",",$facilitiesgroup2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use implode, like:

```
$list = implode(",", $yourArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function:

```
$string = implode(',', $facilitiesgroup1);
echo $string; // Red,Black,White,Green
```